# Prism - ViewModel-First, Navigation API, with Scoped Regions

Tags: navigation, prism, regions

Found a few examples which attempted to couple scope region functionality with Prism's Navigation API, but I don't quite understand how I can put this together using a viewmodel-first approach with implicit datatemplates - each wrapping a UserControl.

Some of my UserControls are wrapped within multiple DataTemplates. These UserControls specify their own regions.

My main shortcoming, is my inability to grasp how it's possible to grab a reference to the Local RegionManager during a Navigation request. How can I notify Prism to create the scoped region, if necessary, and Import the local RegionManager instance inside the Constructor of a child ViewModel which initiates a Navigation request?

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my understanding, **Navigation** with **ScopedRegions** would not be a straight forward feature of **Prism**. There are some workarounds posted however, in order to accomplish it in a quite simple way.

You can look at the following post and discussion thread for handling **ScopeRegionManagers** across **Navigation**:

- [Prism Region Navigation and Scoped Regions](http://blogs.southworks.net/aadami/2011/11/30/prism-region-navigation-and-scoped-regions/)
- [Navigation and ScopedRegions](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/236849)

Basically, Agustin Adami's proposal would be to obtain the scoped **RegionManager** from the ***Region.Add()*** method, through the **NavigationResult** passed in the navigation callback from the ***RequestNavigate()*** method.

The Navigation call then would look as follows:

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate( "MainRegion",
new Uri("HelloWorldView?createRegionManagerScope=true", UriKind.Relative),
(result) =>
{
    var myRegionManager = result.ExtractRegionManager();
    myRegionManager.RequestNavigate("NestedRegion", new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative));
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

One possible approach for setting the scoped **RegionManager** into the child **ViewModel** would be by using a **Shared Service** and get the scoped **RegionManager** from there.

The **Main ViewModel** would store the **RegionManager** as follows:

```
...
bool createRegionManagerScope = true;
var scopedRegionManager = region.Add(view, null, createRegionManagerScope);
var dictionary = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ScopedRegionManagersSharedDictionary>();
dictionary[Names.ScopedRegionManagerName] = scopedRegionManager;
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate( Names.MainRegion,
    new Uri("HelloWorldView", UriKind.Relative));
```

And then, the child **ViewModel** should implement **INavigationAware** in order to retreive and set the scoped **RegionManager** on the ***OnNavigatedTo()*** method like shown below:

```
void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    var dictionary = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ScopedRegionManagersSharedDictionary>();

    this.regionManager = dictionary[Names.ScopedRegionManagerName];
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps, Regards.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How exactly will the child viewmodel instance (the one we just navigated to) receive the local/scoped RegionManager, allowing it to perform its own Navigation?

From the look of things, the primary ViewModel that initiated navigation to the child receives the scoped region manager, and therefore performs another navigation request to a grand child viewmodel.

So confused.

Comment: This implementation would navigate to a predefined **View** in the _**Nested Region**_. If you want to manage Navigation from the child **ViewModel**, you could store the **Scoped RegionManager** into a **_Dictionary_** on a **Shared Service** for example, and when navigating to the child **ViewModel** you could retreive the **Scoped RegionManager** reference from the dictionary on the **_OnNavigatedTo()_** method. I updated the answer to show this other approach.